# Where is HtmlEncode in Asp.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html-encode

I have a custom `IHtmlHelper` extension method that uses `TagBuilder` and returns an `HtmlString`.  I can no longer pass `tagBuiler.ToString()` to the `HtmlString` constructor as that just returns the typename now.

I see I can use the `tabBuiler.WriteTo(TextWriter, IHtmlEncoder)` method but I don't know exactly how to get my hands on an object that implments `IHtmlEncoder`.  I see encoders in both `System.Text.Encodings.Web` and `Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders`.  But the types in the two namespace don't seem to play well together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HtmlEncoder` in `Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core` is just a wrapper around `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder` to implement `IHtmlEncoder` interface (https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/src/Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core/HtmlEncoder.cs).

You can take `Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.HtmlEncoder.Default` and pass to `WriteTo` method.

From what I see in dev branch MVC moved to using `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder` directly so you wan't need to use `Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.HtmlEncoder` anymore in future.

Comment: Thanks!  I wish there were some consolidated view of the asp.net 5 source so you locate types easier.  :-)

Comment: you can add this dependencie for rc2 :  "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.0.0-rc2-24027"

Comment: the link is now dead

Answer (score 15):

In ASP.NET Core RC2 you can find `HtmlDecode` in `System.Net.WebUtility`:

- [GitHub source of System.Net.WebUtility](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/fd8ecb0f6a965794e16ea0cef5de53c9c59e7b7b/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Net/WebUtility.cs)

In your project.json import dependency system.net.utilities

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.0.0-rc2-24027"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As for RC1 update 1, here is how it is done:

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

...

HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode("...");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode or decode as:

System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()