# Sanitizing HTML - Get Some Unknown Encoding?

Tags: encoding, .net-core, html-sanitizing

I am using [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) to parse input in `.NET Core` prevent `XSS Injections`. HtmlSanitizer implements [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) - I have no idea what Angle Sharp does, but it encodes some characters, like so:

Input:

`&#33;@#$%^&*()_+{}:"<>?~`

Output:

`&#33;@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}:"&lt;&gt;?~`

Note that `<`, `>`, and `&` got encoded as `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp`, respectively. I have two questions here:

1. What is this encoding?
2. (Optional) Is there a way to use AngleSharp, or some other library, to undo it?

Side note - all the harmful stuff gets stripped out as needed, this format change happens on "safe" html anyway, just to point out that I am not undoing any security features of the library so we don't have a long discussion on that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you knew what the encoding was, you would likely know from the information posted. @AlanLarimer

Comment: HTML encoding / decoding is built into Asp.Net.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924496/where-is-htmlencode-in-asp-net-5) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

These strings are HTML encoded. The purpose of html encoding is to prevent XSS, but since I am already stripping any potentially harmful code, it's just overkill in my case. More detail can be found in this answer (quote copied from there):

[HTML.Encode() - What/How does it prevent scripting security problems in ASP .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014593/html-encode-what-how-does-it-prevent-scripting-security-problems-in-asp-net)

> - The less-than character (<) is converted to `&lt;`.
> - The greater-than character (>) is converted to `&gt;`.
> - The ampersand character (&) is converted to `&amp;`.
> - The double-quote character (") is converted to `&quot;`.
> - Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80
>     is converted to `&#<number>`, where
>      is the ASCII character value.

You can html encode and decode strings in `.NET Core` using a built in tool, as described [here](http://www.tech-coder.com/2016/07/htmlencode-and-htmldecode-in-aspnet_4.html).